# Tele-substitution mechanism

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

According to IUPAC goldbook:

> A tele-substituion is a substitution reaction in which the entering
>   group takes up a position more than one atom away from the atom to
>   which the leaving group was attached:

[image]

And that's the only example given. What is the mechanism of this reaction?

Comment: Have you drawn it correctly?  If you got this compound, NC1=NC=CN2C1=NN=C2 I could perhaps see a Dimroth rearrangement.

Comment: My smiles should be NC1=CN=CN2C1=NN=C2 (the N and C got transposed) but if this is the product, I can see a Dimroth.

Comment: Please elaborate. The image was taken from the IUPAC gooldbook.

Comment: Hi @Marko I'm wondering whether or not there is a mistake.  I've checked out the Gold book which references Pure and Applied Chemistry, 1994, 66, 1077 but this doesn't go any further.  Reaxys reaction query as starting material doesn't give the reaction; instead the literature search gives the following paper, Tet Lett 1974, 4539 http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040403901922130 which is very close to giving an explanation.  I'm guessing that that paper will provide the answer and show that there's an error in the Gold book.

Comment: Even if it is close to an explanation, I can't access it.

Comment: I can only access the first page.  Nevertheless, I'll contact IUPAC and tell them that they should double check it.

Comment: http://web4.uwindsor.ca/users/j/jlichaa/reference.nsf/0/10ff8b04ff3a317885256d88005720f6/$FILE/ejic-2002-1269-arene-Cr-rose.pdf - but not about azacyclic

Comment: this is similar http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jo00862a005